# Method to compute empirical derivative about some point

Tags: optimization, derivative, numerics

I have black-box access to some function and I want to compute the derivative about the point X. Is there a method that does this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation. Or did you have a more specific question?

Comment: @DaveKielpinski No this was it. There's at least one notion of a "simplex gradient" that was introduced for this reason: this inspires me to look further.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation

Or did you have a more specific question?

(posted following @gung's encouragement above)

Comment: Thank you for pointing in the right direction.  I think Wikipedia skirts around the issue, though: the key is to compute the derivative *while obtaining an error estimate for the answer.*  It doesn't seem to address that issue at all.

Comment: Error estimates for derivatives are not mentioned in the question. If you want to create a new question around that, I can try to answer. Upvoting my current answer would be encouraging in that regard :)

Comment: Although error estimates were not mentioned in the question, I was trying to put forward the view that any discussion of numerical differentiation in such a context (a "black box") on this site (which concerns *statistical* analysis) *needs* to acknowledge the possibility of making such estimates and the importance of doing so.  Indeed, whenever the answer to a question here on CV is a single line, that's a sign the answer is incomplete and perhaps ought to be expanded (or perhaps the question ought to be closed as unsuitable for our format).

Comment: That's an interesting point of view. You're obviously one of the people who runs things around here, so do what you like, but I wouldn't have assumed that. I just try to answer the questions as they're posed, and the OP was satisfied. 